# dictionary of dictionaries to dataframe with first keys as headers second as columns d2 values as data

Tags: pandas, dictionary, dataframe, header

I have a dict of dicts like this:

```
dict_ = {'c1':{'m1':.9,'m2':.6,'m3':.7},'c2':{'m1':{.3,'m2':.4,'m3':.4},'c3':{.2,'m2':.1,'m3':.6}
```

I want a dataframe that has headers like

```
        c1                     c2                        c3
m1      m2      m3      m1     m2      m3           m1      m2      m3 
.9      .6      .7      .3     .4     .4            .2       .1     .6
```

Anyone know how to do this or have a better way of formatting?

FYI I have

```
header = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([list(metrics_dict.keys()),
                                 list(metrics_dict['c1'])],
                                names=['cs','ms'])

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=header,data=1,index=range(1))

for key, value in metrics_dict.items():
    for metric, ms in value.items():
        df[key][metric].iloc[0] = ms
```

but it won't replace the values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `dict_` definition had two misplaced parentheses. The correct definition seems to be:

```
dict_ = {'c1':{'m1': .9,
               'm2': .6,
               'm3': .7},
         'c2':{'m1': .3,
               'm2': .4,
               'm3': .4},
         'c3':{'m1': .2,
               'm2': 1,
               'm3': .6}
        }
```

To get a MultiIndex in the columns, one way is to manually convert the dictionary keys into tuples that hold the levels of the desired MultiIndex:

```
tups = {(k1, k2): v for k1, subdict in dict_.iteritems() for k2, v in subdict.iteritems()}

# Need to specify index since each tuple only points to a single value
pd.DataFrame(tups, index=[0])

    c1             c2             c3
    m1   m2   m3   m1   m2   m3   m1   m2   m3
0  0.9  0.6  0.7  0.3  0.4  0.4  0.2  0.1  0.6
```